# Is there a recommended idiomatic way to adapt a Java Optional to a Kotlin nullable?

Tags: java, kotlin, option-type, nullable

I am writing Kotlin code that uses a Java library which uses `Optional`s, and I would prefer to use Kotlin's nullable idiom in Kotlin-world.

For example, my library may have a function

```
Optional<Foo> getFoo(String fooId) {
  ...
}
```

and in my Kotlin program I want to

```
foo: Foo? = /* something, something */ getFoo(fooId)
```

I know that I can do something like

```
lateinit var foo: Foo?
val fooOpt = getFoo(fooId)
if(fooOpt.isPresent) foo = fooOpt.get()
else foo = null
```

But, given that Java's `Optional` serves pretty much the same purpose as a nullable, this seems unnecessarily verbose, even if I collapse it to

```
val foo: Foo? = getFoo(fooId).orElse(null)
```

Comment: It should just be `getFoo(fooId).orElse(null)`. You should not `get()`. Is that still verbose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a built-in method for this in the Kotlin standard library - [`getOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm.optionals/java.util.-optional/get-or-null.html).

```
val foo = getFoo(fooId).getOrNull()
```

Note that if you use `orElse(null)`, you should not call `get` first.

```
// this also works, but
// the difference here is that foo here will be a platform type,
// unless you say ": Foo?" explicitly
val foo = getFoo(fooId).orElse(null)
```